# output of threads happening more than as wanted (not data race)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

String[] urls contains urls as strings. The inputstream is working fine. This problem has to do with threading. There should be the same number of threads as elements in String[] urls and each thread should deal with one element in String[] urls while all running concurrently without data race. That seems to all work here except for the each thread dealing with one String[] urls element part. However, as it's easier to explain with an example. Let's say String[] urls contains two urls. In that case, I get twice as many inputstream as I want. Something that should have "Cat Dog Fish" instead gets "Cat Cat Dog Dog Fish Fish". When String[] urls contains only one element it works fine but not when more than that.

I did try removing the for loop in the run() method (as it should only be happening once per thread), and changing the `URL url=new URL(urls[i])` to `URL url=new URL(urls[t])` but I then get an error saying "Local variable t defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" and I do not want t to be final as it is changing depending on the index.

```
public void readData(String[] urls) {
        Thread[] arrThr=new Thread[urls.length];
        for (int t=0; t<arrThr.length; t++) {
            arrThr[t]=new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 
                    for (int i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
                        String str="";
                        try { 
                            URL url=new URL(urls[i]);
                            URLConnection c=url.openConnection();
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                            String line;
                            while (( line = in.readLine())!=null)
                                if (line.contains("<br>")) 
                                    str += line;    
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //synchronized method calling here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        for (int p=0; p<arrThr.length; p++)
            arrThr[p].start();
        for (int q=0; q<arrThr.length; q++)
            try {
                arrThr[q].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making each thread handle all the URLs. Remove the redundant `i` loop inside your `run()` method and declare `final int i = t;` as the first statement in your `t` loop. Finally, make the `urls` parameter final and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Question though, I thought final meant that the value does not change. So then what does the final do here?

Comment: `final` for variables always means that the variable can only be assigned a value one time. It is scope-dependent though, so a variable declared inside a loop can be final - think of it as a different variable declaration for every time through the loop, in the same way that method-local variables are initialized freshly every time the method is called.

Comment: @MobBarley `final` does something else:  It allows the inner class (i.e., the Runnable) to reference the "variable".  Normally, it would make no sense for a method running in one thread to access a local variable on the stack of some other thread, but the `final` means that `i` is not really a _variable_ at all:  You can think of it as just a name for a value, and that's how the Java compiler _does_ think of it:  The anonymous inner class effectively has a hidden instance variable, `final int i`, that gets set to the value of the local variable, `final int i` when the new instance is created.